# Is it possible to have IPython qtconsole open as the default python console in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, ipython

Whenever I open a Python script in Spacemacs, I do `C-c C-p` to launch a console embedded - a console that is, by default, actually an iPython console.

Here is what I would love to be able to accomplish. I would like to configure it so that when I do `C-c C-p`, actually an embedded (i.e. not in a new external window outside Spacemacs) **iPython qtconsole** is created/opened instead of normal ipython console.

Note that I am not interested at all in working with Jupyter notebooks. I just want to have an ipython qtconsole inside Spacemacs.

Is such a task possible to achieve? How could I proceed to do have it like that?

Comment: Wouldn't you need a version of emacs that was built as a Qt application in order for this to be possible? As far as I know, there is no such thing.  But perhaps I am misunderstanding your request.  Reference: https://qtconsole.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#embedding-the-qtconsole-in-a-qt-application

Comment: @deprecated what makes me think it would not need a version of emacs built as a Qt application, is the fact that other emacs pacakges seem to be able to do that. For instance, take a look [link](https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook). The problem is that all packages like it, that implement ipython qtconsole embedded in emacs/supermacs, aim at linking jupyter notebooks. But nothing prevents one to use ipython qtconsole without notebooks. So, I think if ipython qtconsole can be within emacs for jupyter notebooks, it could be as standalone too.

Comment: Yes, I know about EIN.  But that has nothing to do with the ipython qtconsole.  It uses its own native Emacs interface to the jupyter kernel.  It seems very powerful, but personally I found it difficult to use.  I prefer to use ob-ipython: https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython

Comment: So, I think it would be best if you could specify exactly what features you are looking for, then maybe someone will be able to better help you.  Why is the emacs integration with the ipython terminal console not good enough?  Is it that you want to display figures inline? That can be done in org-mode with ob-ipython or just plain ob-python.

Comment: @deprecated It surprises me that EIN achieves inline plotting in a terminal within Spacemacs without ipython qtconsole, since it then means they had to implement their own python shell. Anyways, what I need is exactly to be able to plot figures inline (what I do not want is to have to work with notebooks). Hence mimicking Spyder. There is no Spacemacs layer for `ob-python`. Question remains whether it would work if installed directly a traditional package.